# How to make a chase the button game in python with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

What I am trying to do is so when the mouse is in the button radius I want the button to move.
My code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
#Creating a win
win = Tk()
#Giving a Function To The Button
def btn1():
print("I Don't Know Your Name")
#Creating The Button
button = Button(win, text="Click Me To Print SomeThing", command=btn1)
#put on screen
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: move in what context? Where is your code ? What is the problem?

Comment: there is no problem just I couldn't figure a way to make a button move when the mouse is approaching it, and there aren't any tutorials on python.

Comment: Move the button to where?

Comment: *there aren't any tutorials on python* thats simply not true and tkinter is well documented for this. Please go ahead and do a quick research about `widget.bind('<Enter>', event_function)` and think about the open question how you want the button to be moved.

Comment: thx this solved my problem!!